# Delegates called after phone call

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am working on a music player application. While playing a song, if a phone call is received, the player pause playing. After the call, the application will enter foreground automatically with the player in paused state. I would like to know the delegates which are called during receiving call and ending the call so as to keep player playing. For example, when home button pressed `applicationDidEnterBackground` will fire and when Application launched again `applicationWillEnterForeground` will fire. Like wise what are the delegates called (in AppdDelegate.m) when user taps on 'End Call' button. I am using AVPlayer to play audio.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, but if you are using `AVAudioPlayer`, you can use the following delegate methods to pause/play your music on the beginning and end of an interruption (like a phone call).

```
- (void)audioPlayerBeginInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
{
    [player pause];
}

- (void)audioPlayerEndInterruption:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
{
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
}
```